# Redirect 301 not working because of Long Dash (special character)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I've got an issue when redirecting one of my blog's url:

http://suitelife.com/category/moving-to-barcelona-tips/barcelona-legality%E2%80%93barcelona-shopping-health-public-transport

As you can see the `%E2%80%93` is a pain in the a**, I looked at diverse forums, but no solution there appeared to solve my situation.

I put that line in the `.htaccess` :

```
RewriteRule ^category/moving-to-barcelona-tips/barcelona-legality([^.%E2%80%93])barcelona-shopping-health-public-transport(.*)$ category/moving-to-barcelona-tips/barcelona-day-life$1 [R=301,L]
```

P.S: I've got RewriteEngine On and RewriteBase /  etc. I've already redirected other URLs, just this one is not working.

Many thanks in advance! :)

Florian

Answer (score 1):

You can use take regex help to avoid matching that character:

```
RewriteRule ^category/moving-to-barcelona-tips/barcelona-legality.*?barcelona-shopping-health-public-transport(.*)$ category/moving-to-barcelona-tips/barcelona-day-life$1 [R=301,L,B]
```

Note use of `.*?` instead of that character to match any arbitrary string there.